# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**My attempt:**

I used the fact that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} \neq 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ doesn´t converges. So, I checked that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left |(-1)^{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) \right |=1
\end{align*}
i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left |(-1)^{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) \right |\neq0 \Longrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left |(-1)^{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) \right | \text{does not converges}
\end{align*}

**My doubt:**

Is this implication correct?
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left |(-1)^{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) \right | \text{does not converges} \Longrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})  \text{ does not converges}
\end{align}

Comment: The last implication is false (e.g. $\sum (-1)^n/n$) but you don't need it since $|a_n|\not\to 0\implies a_n\not\to 0$.

Comment: That direct implication is not correct, but there was no need to take the absolute value. A limit that does not exist certainly does not equal $0$.

Comment: $\lim |a_n|=1$ means $\lim a_n\neq 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}} $ is not $ 0 $, then your series diverges.